# How to completely hide a div with bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, hide

I'm working on a website which displays notifications (invalid login details, registered succesfully, etc) in a div above the main content div. The displaying of notifications works like a charm, but I would also like for the user to be able to hide the notifications by clicking a button.

To do this I've used the 'collapse' class from bootstrap. This is however apparently the wrong approach, because the div doesn't disappear completely, but instead leaves a small stroke visible. I figured this is probably expected behaviour and I shouldn't use the collapse class at all. So now my question is: How do I neatly hide a div with bootstrap, when a button is clicked?

My current code is:

```
<div id="notifications_errors" class="hero-unit collapse in">
    <a class="close pull-right" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#notifications_errors" href="#">&times;</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Bootstrap does not prevent you from doing:

```
$('#someButton).click(function(event){ $('#someDiv').toggle() })
```

Granted you included jQuery in your project [and you should, if you are using any BS js plugin].

Comment: I know, I was just wondering if there was a more "bootstrappy" way of doing it. Thanks, eitherway!

Comment: Bootstrap is simply using jQuery in a similar manner. The problem you describe is one of styles, not jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Try moving your content inside a separate `div` block, its most likely the css for the `hero-unit` class is conflicting with the `collapse` css.

```
<div id="notifications_errors" class="collapse in">**
  <div class="hero-unit">
    <a class="close pull-right" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#notifications_errors" href="#">&times;</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

This should let the .height:0 and overflow:hidden properties of the .collapse class work properly. (I had a similar issue trying to use collapse with the alert formatting and this fixed it for me)